# Swap Using Pointer Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a beginner of C programming. The code of interchange v[i] and v[j] from the book is :

```
void swap2(char *v[], int i, int j) {
    char *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

I am not sure whether I got this correct. I think `v` here is an array which stores pointers, so `v[i]` and `v[j]` are pointers. Here temp is also a char pointer, but it makes me feel that `temp = v[i];` this statement says a pointer `v[i]` is assigned to an address, and I think if we change `char *temp` into `char temp` will make the function correct. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: If you made `temp` a `char` instead of `char *`, you'd be assigning a `char *` to a `char`, and you'd probably get a compilation error...

Comment: A pointer **is** an address.

Answer (score 3):

The function is correct as is.

`v` is declared as an array of `char *`.  So each `v[i]` is a `char *`.  Therefore, you use a `char *` when performing the swap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why we can write "temp = v[i]" instead of "*temp = v[i]". I think even if temp is known as a pointer, the * should still be shown.

Comment: No, because `*temp` is of type `char`, so it would be a type mismatch.

Comment: @IshanM That won't work because `temp` hasn't been initialized to point anywhere yet.

Answer (score 1):

> this statement says a pointer `v[i]` is assigned to an address

You seem to be confusing an array of characters with an array of character pointers: `v[i]` is simply the i-th member of an *array consisting of* `char *`.

In C everything is passed *by value*, so are the pointers. You are right in assuming that `v[]` is an array storing `char` pointers.

The code is valid because the pointers are being swapped, not the `char` variables pointed at: `v[i]` and `v[j]` are pointers, therefore `temp` should be a pointer as well.

The following test code demonstrates it from the *caller's* point of view: you can easily observe what is happening in your function.  Pointers are being passed as values which are getting swapped, but the `char` variables that they point at are left as they are (`b` and `c` in this example).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap2(char *v[], int i, int j) {
    char *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}

int main (void)
{
    char a = '1', b = '2', c = '3', d = '4', e = '5';
    char *v[5] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%p:%c ", (void*)(v[i]), *(v[i]));
    printf ("\n");

    swap2(v, 1, 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%p:%c ", (void*)(v[i]), *(v[i]));
    printf ("\n");
    printf("b = %c\n", b);
    printf("c = %c\n", c);
return 0;
}
```